# Restore non-cdb backup into pdb database

Tags: oracle

I haven't found any information on is it possible to restore a Oracle non-cdb 19.8 backup into a container-database PDB (still 19c) , or not.
The method i have found is not suitable for my situation (convert non-cdb to pdb using DBMS_PDB.DESCRIBE - that seems to imply that the database type is converted + all data is copied during this operation, which is not the same as restoring from a backup).
*Export/import/Golden Gate are not viable options for me.

Has anyone had a similar challenge and what was the best way to get a non-cdb to get into pdb form.

Comment: If you are talking about restoring from RMAN backups, this is not possible. The data dictionary architecture and reliance on system-level objects is completely different. You will have to go through the database type conversion to ensure that all of those references are modified correctly.

Comment: so i need to convert the source database to a cdb you mean ?

Comment: Convert the source to a PDB.

Comment: Thanks________________

Answer (score -1):

Good example shown here
"Creating PDB from a non-CDB"

https://shivanandarao-oracle.com/2015/10/02/creating-pluggable-databases-part-2/#CreatingPDBfromanonCDB